# How to iterate over a ColorStateList?

Tags: java, android

How can I iterate over a `ColorStateList`? I tried with

```
ColorStateList colors = getTextColors();

for(Color color : colors) { // gives "foreach not applicable to type 'android.content.res.ColorStateList'"
}
```

So, how can I iterate over all values of a `ColorStateList`?

Comment: According to [`ColorStateList` javadoc](http://javadox.com/com.google.android/android/4.1.1.4/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html), this class is not iterable, does not have a method returning list / collection / iterator for a collection of colors.

Comment: good point, guess you mean it doesn't implement the necessary interface? But then, how do I get all its values?

Comment: You don't, insofar as it has no values. It has rules: if the view in in state X, use color Y. Those rules are not part of the public API, other than via `getColorForState()`.